# When are QLCs much less efficient?

Tags: erlang

In practice, Query List Comprehensions seem to be fine for all uses of Mnesia and ets/dets tables. Are there any operations (or types of operation) that are significantly more efficient than their QLC equivalents?

(I'm thinking along the lines of the answer in [Which is more expensive to the RAM, A query list comprehension, or a mnesia index_read?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6730302/which-is-more-expensive-to-the-ram-a-query-list-comprehension-or-a-mnesia-inde/6731262#6731262))

Answer (score 1):

For large data sets I'm using mnesia:select (http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/mnesia.html#select-2). In my tests it works 1.5 time faster than same QLC queries.